# optional file uploading validation

Tags: validation, cakephp, file-upload

is there any way to make file uploading not required in cakephp 
i've tried setting allowEmpty to true  , and required to flase but didn't work

```
'pic' => array(
              'uploadError'=>array(      
                              'rule'=>'uploadError',
                              'message'=>'The image upload failed',
                              'allowEmpty'=>true  
                             )
             )
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP Form Validation only on Entering Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094712/cakephp-form-validation-only-on-entering-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your HTML attribute Required to false on the HTML element in your View.

Here are some examples:

For Cake:

```
echo $this->Form->input('pic', array('type' => 'file', **'required' => false**));
```

For native PHP:

```
<input type="file" name="data['Upload']['pic']" **required**>
```

Comment: I think i should use something called "before Validate" but there is no enough info about it in the cakephp documentation

Comment: Can you try this? I tried this and it worked :) 'pic' => array(
   'required' => array(
   'allowEmpty')
  )
 );

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code in your view.ctp. I think the default value of *required* in latest version of CakePHP is **false** or maybe you put *validation* in your Model?

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('pic', array('type' => 'file', 'required' => false)); ?>
```

Comment: the code that @ndm gave http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094712/cakephp-form-validation-only-on-entering-data
has useful info , read the second answer

Comment: but where should i use beforeValidate ?

Comment: try to read the answer, maybe it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23777089/how-to-uploading-images-in-cakephp-2-0