# image type validation and filesize validation using cakephp

Tags: validation, cakephp

Hi i have this validaton for the images that validates only jpg and png types and also i aadded a filesize that is only 5mb. I want that when i will not select an image it will bypass. So no validation for selecting images. What happend is when i did not select an image it will validates to `select valid image`. How will i able to do this that when im not selecting an image it will not validate. Heres my validation below

```
'images' => [
            'extension' => [
                'rule' => [
                    'extension',
                    ['png', 'jpg']
                ],
                'allowEmpty'=>['Empty'],
                'message' => 'Select valid image'
            ],
            'fileSize' =>[
                'rule'=>
                    'fileSize', 
                    ['<=', '5mb'],
                'message' => 'Image must be less than 5mb'
            ]
        ],
```

this is just a simple one. Any help is muchly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP Form Validation only on Entering Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094712/cakephp-form-validation-only-on-entering-data)

Comment: ahm can you post your code? below

Comment: "my" code? I don't know what you are referring to, a code example for how to solve the problem can be found in the linked questions answer.